# Can´t implement PrimeFaces media for show PDF file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm triying to display a PDF preview in my page but I can´t figure out how achive this. According to PrimeFaces showcase it's just enough placing the relative file path but it doesn't work.

I tried copy the file into the same folder where mi XHTML file is and got the same result.
I've also try adding cache="false" and player="pdf" attributes.

```
<p:media value="#{mb.getStream()}" width="100%" cache="false" player="pdf">
  Your browser can't display pdf,
  <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/TEST.pdf">click</h:outputLink> to download pdf instead.
</p:media>
```

I've add to my Managedbean a method which returns a StreamedContent() but I'm still getting the same result that says "Your browser can't display pdf,click to download pdf instead."

```
public StreamedContent getStream() throws IOException {
    File f = new File("C:\\TEST.pdf");
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println("********** EXISTS");
        try ( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f) ) {
            return DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .contentType("application/pdf")
                    .name(f.getName())
                    .stream(() -> is)
                    .build();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("*-----FILE DOESNT EXISTS");
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
}//method
```

Comment: You might want the check the docs around rules for Streaming media content: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/dynamiccontent

Also does your code work if you have a URL to a PDF in there like the PF showcase?  Just ruling things out by getting something working first before trying to stream.

Comment: Thanks @Melloware you helped me to pay more attention to the little erros before triying other things.

Answer (score 0):

At the end was a security configuration declared in the web.xml. The project neds a ClickjackFilter and the option for allow render content from the same origin was in DENY mode. I fixed it changing the mode to SAMEORIGIN as it says in their documentation: https://github.com/vishank848/owasp-esapi-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/filters/ClickjackFilter.java
and it works, my problem was nothing related with JSF or PrimeFaces.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).